# Can I color points in highcharts time series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hey I have an example of Highchart timeseries.
In this example, I get all the points as array of small arrays(each array is a pair of x and y).
I would like to know if I could color specific point in current format using the fillColor attribute,if so how can I do it?

I want to **highlight** specific points in the time series graph, how can I do it?

```js
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                        'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Exchange rate'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                data: data
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I want to highlight specific points in the time series graph, how can I do it?

Comment: yeah by giving each point it's own color and setting [colorByPoint](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.colorByPoint) to true

Comment: not a good idea, I want to color specific points and not random colors to all points.

Comment: it seems you don't even have to set the colorByPoint property. example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kd7s9625/)

Comment: How do you identify your `specific` points? I think you can just have a function that scans your data array and for each check if it's a `specific` one and set a `color` attribute on that point like @RahulSharma pointed out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two possibilites,

1) declare the color in the point object

```
{
   x: 0,
   y: 10,
   color: 'red'
}
```

2) set a color by [point.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update)

```
chart.series[0].data[0].update({
  color: 'red'
});
```